# Storing NSMutableDictionary a C struct with a pointer to a link list

Tags: objective-c

I have this C struct (allocated with malloc, thus in heap) I want to store in NSMutableDictionary, because I want to avoid re-creating the C struct which is a complicated process.

Usually with C struct I know I can use a NSData object to store the bits then put it in Objective-C containers such as NSArray and NSDictionary. However, the struct I want to save contains a pointer to a C link list, which is why I want to avoid re-creating. I'd rather just saving the pointer in a container like NSDictionary and fetch it when I need it.

The question is, what's the best way to be able to reuse the struct without re-creating it?

I'm thinking of storing the pointer to the struct themselves. Since pointer is really just a number, can I store it in NSNumber? If I can, what do I use? Unsigned long long?

Example: `[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedLongLong:aPointer];`

PS: This is for iPhone BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pointer is not a number (at least not in the sense of `NSNumber`). But it is a value. And in fact you can use `[NSValue valueWithPointer:myPtr]`.

Comment: That reminds me. I've used it before and I forgot! Thank you.